# where in the rqt source code is the tab handling?

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I would like to know where I can find the rqt perspective tab handling, e.g. where in the source code are they created?

I guess it's somewhere in the qt_gui_core (https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core), but I couldn't find anything.

edit: I mean the tabs in the picture below (open rqt and add some plugins over each other):

[image: image description]

**Explanation of my goal:**
I want to add several rqt plugins (mostly my own plugins), add them to a single rqt perspective and create tabs like in the picture above. Then I want do switch between this tabs from a ros node, depending on which tab is most relevant.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213992/where-in-the-rqt-source-code-is-the-tab-handling?/) by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2015-07-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-17**:
What do you mean by tab handling? The plugins? Or Tabs? Like in Browser?
The ones like in browser are done by Qt it is not in the source of rqt.

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-07-17**:
yes I meant tabs like in the browser. Ok, than I guess it's impossible to switch between these tabs from a ros node.

**Comment by [cyborg-x1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1900/cyborg-x1/) on 2015-07-18**:
Well then, have fun ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As @cyborg-x1 mentioned, the tabbing functionality is part of Qt.

For the following, first, a disclaimer: the UIs I've implemented have used librviz, not rqt, so I've never had to worry about inter-widget communication (I created and set up the `QMainWindow` myself). Also, all my Qt work has been strictly in C++; any pyQt is possibly different. And, rqt may incorporate/hide/expose functionality that makes everything below irrelevant...I just don't know. With that said...perhaps it'll be of assistance.

The Qt [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmainwindow.html) provides the ability to tabify [QDockWidgets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdockwidget.html). When a `QDockWidget`'s docking location changes, it emits a `dockLocationChanged` signal; with an appropriate Qt 'connection' to a slot, one can program reactions to widget relocations.

Through various (rather convoluted) means, you can programmtically manipulate `QDockWidgets` through the `QMainWindow`. Not the easiest item to access, but I've successfully retrieved it in an RViz `Display` subclass via the following:

```
QMainWindow* main = static_cast(context_->getWindowManager()->getParentWindow());
```

where `context_` is an (inherited from `Display`) instance of `rviz::DisplayContext` (as implemented by the `rviz::VisualizationManager`).

I don't recommend going down this path, but if you do, that should give you a bit of a start on what will be involved.

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2015-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-07-17**:
I extended my post to explain a bit better what I want

**Comment by [sam_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/22467/sam_123/) on 2015-07-17**:
so if I understand you right, the best approach would be to create my own QMainWindow and add there my rqt plugins in a QDockWidget, right? Do you know how I can do that (all my rqt plugins are in C++)?

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-07-17**:
Here's my understanding of what you want: to be able to programatically choose which tab is showing (based on relevance, as defined by you). What you need, then, is some way to reference and select a particular tab widget. This is not a trivial task. (More in next comment...)

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-07-17**:
I do not know if rqt provides the functionality you desire. I do know that I've done similar things in my own Qt UI. I do know that you can obtain a reference to QMainWindow in an RViz Display (and then manipulate the DockWidgets). I can't determine the 'best' approach here...but it won't be easy.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-07-17**:
In case this isn't clear: an rqt plugin is, at root, a Qt QDockWidget. The issue is that rqt provides a *container* for plugins -- the widgets do not 'know' about each other, and the container may not provide a way to access them. If that's correct, any workaround requires (not easy) hacking.

**Comment by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) on 2015-07-17**:
Now that I think more about it -- you might be able to avoid your issue by consolidating into one plugin, using a [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html) in there. Each of your current plugins would become a tab in your single new rqt plugin, to be manipulated as you like...